# 'rendered' event not firing in meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to use JQuery's autocomplete feature on an  field in a meteor template. As far as I have been able to research, you're supposed to do this by hooking the template's 'rendered' event to a handler that calls JQ's $(someElement).autocomplete() function. When I try this, nothing happens, and as far as I can tell my event handler for the template's 'rendered' event is never even run.

Here's the template:

```
<template name="loginOrWelcome">
  {{#if isLoggedIn}}
    <p>You are logged in as {{getUsername}}.</p>
    <button type="button" id="logout">Log out</button>
  {{else}}
    <form class="login">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Who are you?" id="loginName"/>
      <button type="button" id="submit">Log in</button>
      <span id="errorSpan"></span>
    </form>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Here's the handler:

```
Template.loginOrWelcome.events({
    "rendered": function() {
      var users = userCollection.find({});
      var arr = [];
      for(user in users) {
        arr.push(user.name);
      }
      alert("rendered: found " + arr.length + " names"); // This never pops up. Ever.
      $("#loginName").autocomplete({
        "source": arr
      });
    }
  });
```

This is in meteor 1.0. Note, I am a total meteor noob, so if I'm missing something super obvious, please feel free to enlighten me.

Comment: Meteor has a full-featured autocomplete package - https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/autocomplete

Comment: Note: something's wrong on the atmosphere.js site for autocomplete. All of the `source` links are returning 404s.

Comment: It's a known issue, please [vote here](https://github.com/percolatestudio/atmosphere-beta/issues/116)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use Template.loginOrWelcome.rendered (https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-rendered). As a test you can do

```
    Template.loginOrWelcome.rendered = function() {
        console.log("get collections");
        var users = userCollection.find({});
        for (user in users) {
            console.log(user);
        }
    }
```

You may want to limit the user collection. Also instead of doing isLoggedIn, I think {{currentUser}} is more common (https://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/currentUser).